# How to change resolution (not density) in Socketeq's windowsandroid?

Tags: android, android-emulator, resolution, android-x86

The main querstion is in title. I googled really hard for parameter in init.rc, build.prop. Searched what files are responsible for setting resolution, but found nothing.

And maybe someone knows how to switch between portrait and landscape modes on the fly?

Are there any resources on hotkeys for this emulator? I used to run Android on Oracles VM and its hotkeys don't work in socketeq emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun fact is, I'm telling you the following because this answer helped me out; however, this might help you:
add the following line to your 'build.prop' file, to over-ride these settings, maybe?
anyway, it's:

[ro.sf.lcd_density=120](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1773hv/android_403_ported_to_windows_78_natively/c83oytf)

(clicking it will take you to the reddit page where I found it).

this worked for me, but my actual home pages and other 'desktop' screens were still much smaller...I'm hoping some guys at XDA Developers will post some new stuff on this; meanwhile, I'm also hoping some of the few apps that currently work with WindowsAndroid might include video stuff, like Youtube, Netflix, Hulu, the system video player, and that these apps, in full-screen mode, might fill the space better.

Hope this helped you a little--the way you posed your question certainly helped me.

Thanks, guys
Mike Denney

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of the program is dependent on the size of the WindowsAndroid window. IF you have a big desktop resolution (1366 by 768 or higher), WindowsAndroid will run in tablet mode, and phone mode if you have a low resolution.